# php variable in regex?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, regex, variables

I have a variable $word and I'd like to match it in my select statement
somethig like this: "select * from table where column regex '[0-9]$word'"
but this doesnt work, so how can i put a variable in a regular exprssion?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must only put it correctly in SQL query, for example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP 'prefix_".$word."'");
```

But you need to remember that the variable data needs to be properly escaped, i think that addslashes() would be enough.

Comment: i would be very thankful if you could vote on my answer too ;]

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `preg_quote()` to escape your string:

```
$sql = "select * from table where column regexp '[0-9]" . preg_quote($word) . "'";
```

There will be some issues because MySQL (assuming this is your DB) may have a completely different idea of which characters are special than PCRE.